# How can I composite these 3 Layers?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, layers

I'm attempting to add a couple of filters to a render layer that sits between two others. I suspect my problem arises from a misunderstanding of how layers work, as my "flames" layer renders on the "door" layer as well as its own... Anyway I can't get a result at all. If anyone can give me some pointers, I'd be much obliged. [image]
[image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4456" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4456/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compose this way because you use Glass shadier on the window. Glass isn't just transparent color - it have refraction and reflection, that's why it renders non-transparent. So you can try different things:

**1. Just remove window or move it on different layer.**

Then use **Mask layer**. If I move window on this layer:

[image]

The setup for render layer flames will look like (pay attention to the **mask layer** option):

[image]

and door of course:

[image]

result will be look like:

[image]

**2. add glow effect by threshold**

in this case you should not to separate render layers. Render all in one frame and in glare node set threshold to value between 0 and 1

[image]

Comment: Thank you Crantisz for taking the time with this. That's very helpful. I need to get back to the file to try out your alternatives.